# Cannot Install Spotify Gnome Support/Dependency Problems

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, package-management, spotify

Error is as follows:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>   spotify-client-gnome-support: Depends: spotify-client-qt (=
>   1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1) but 1:0.6.2.291.gcccc1f5.116-1 is to be
>   installed E: Broken packages

Basically `spotify-client-qt` is too recent under both my Ubuntu/Xubuntu installations.

I cannot force version so as to regress under synaptic either.  Can I get an old copy from somewhere?  Or will Spotify be updated any time soon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in their Packages file:

```
Package: spotify-client-gnome-support
Version: 1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1
Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.12), spotify-client-qt (= 1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1)
```

-

```
Package: spotify-client-qt
Version: 1:0.6.2.291.gcccc1f5.116-1
Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.14), libc6 (>= 2.6), libqt4-dbus (>= 4.5.0), libqt4-webkit (>= 4.5.0), libqtcore4 (>= 4.5.0), libqtgui4 (>= 4.5.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.0.0), libxss1 (>= 1:1.2.0), usbutils, libssl0.9.8
Recommends: libavcodec52, libavformat52
```

Look at the dependencies for 'spotify-client-gnome-support'. It says "spotify-client-qt (= 1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1)", but the version that's installed is 1:0.6.2.291.gcccc1f5.116-1...

The line should be: "spotify-client-qt (>= 1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1)"

You could create your own repository, or just don't install spotify-client-gnome-support... The latter worked for me ;-)

Edit:
Found this on their forums:
Mathieu Bérard 3 months ago
The functionality provided by spotify-client-gnome-support was integrated in spotify-client-qt with version 1:0.6.1.309.gb871a7d-1 
You can just first remove spotify-client-gnome-support and then upgrade to spotify-client-qt 1:0.6.1.309.gb871a7d-1